# Quarkus Hibernate UnsafeAccess

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, graalvm

I have been facing an issue with my Quarkus application. The application works as expected when running in local development mode, but when it is build as a native image I am facing some strange issues.

Errors encountered:

- The offset of private int java.util.ArrayList.size is accessed without the field being first registered as unsafe accessed.
- org.hibernate.type.serializationexception could not deserialize
- java.io.InvalidClassException: java.util.ArrayList; no valid constructor

I am just posting this question in the case where someone else faces these issues and are stumped about where they are possibly coming from.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up causing these issues for me was, I had installed the [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) dependency from vladmihalcea.
This dependency is not fully supported by quarkus native-image so try changing to [quarkus-hibernate-types](https://github.com/lorislab/quarkus-hibernate-types) instead.